# How to query data efficiently in large mongodb collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have one big mongodb collection (3-million docs, 50 GigaBytes), and it would be very slow to query the data even I have created the indexs.

```
db.collection.find({"C123":1, "C122":2})
```

e.g. the query will be timeout or will be extreme slow (10s at least), even if I have created the separate indexes for `C123` and `C122`.

Should I create more indexs or increase the physical memory to accelerate the querying?

Comment: What's up with the aggregation-framework tag? The query in the question does not use it.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed `aggregate-$match` is the same as `find()`

Comment: It is `indexes` rather than `indexs`.

Answer (score 9):

For such a query you should create compound indexes. One on both fields. And then it should be very efficient. Creating separate indexes won't help you much, because MongoDB engine will use first to get results of first part of query, but second if is used won't help much (or even can slow down in some cases your query because of lookup in indexes table and then in real data again). You can confirm used indexes by using .explain() on your query in shell.

See compound indexes:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-compound/

Also consider sorting directions on both your fields while making indexes.

Comment: Mongodb can merge indexes for a couple of years now, I think. Still, compound should be better.

Comment: Good point @SergioTulentsev, I've made an edit, I knew about merging but in my experience it is not helping much in most cases. However to be honest we should say that.

Comment: It seems that I should have more thought on designing the compound indexes, as there are more than 400 keys in this collection.

Comment: @ppn029012: 400 keys?! In this case, don't bother with compound indexes.  Only maybe for the most frequent combinations (if that's a thing in your app, some combinations being significantly more frequent than others). Just get more hardware.

Comment: You should use maximum as many as you have in your queries, not more. If you quering on 2 fields, don't create 400. Maximum indexes per collection is 64 anyway. You can create indexes in background if you don't want to put down servers.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is really simple.

1. You don't need to create *more* indexes, you need to create the right indexes. Index on field `c124` won't help queries on field `c123`, so no point in creating it.
2. Use better/more hardware. More RAM, more machines (sharding).

Comment: The problem is that mongodb can not finish the query even if I have created the right indexes for each key. Should I have to buy a better hardware to run this statement?

Comment: @ppn029012: The best index to serve this exact query is a compound index on two keys, as  mentioned in Alan's answer. But it is quite likely, that even with it, your current hardware is just not up to the task.

Comment: How big the RAM do I need to operate this 50GB collection?

Comment: @ppn029012: Ideally, 50GB + whatever is needed for indexes. Say, another 10-15 GB. Ideally. Depending on specifics of your application, you could do with less.

Answer (score 2):

- Create Right indices and carefully use compound index. (You can have max. 64 indices per collection and 31 fields in compound index)
- Use mongo side pagination
- Try to find out most used queries and build compound index around that.
- Compound index strictly follow sequence so read documentation and do trials
- Also try covered query for 'summary' like queries

Learned it hard way..

Answer (score 1):

Use `skip` and `limit`. Run a loop for 50000 data at once .

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.skip/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/
example :

```
[
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$myDoc,homepage_domain",
      count: {$sum: 1},
      entry: {
        $push: {
          location_city: "$myDoc.location_city",
          homepage_domain: "$myDoc.homepage_domain",
          country: "$myDoc.country",
          employee_linkedin: "$myDoc.employee_linkedin",
          linkedin_url: "$myDoc.inkedin_url",
          homepage_url: "$myDoc.homepage_url",
          industry: "$myDoc.industry",
          read_at: "$myDoc.read_at"
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
    $limit : 50000
  }, {
    $skip: 50000
  }
],
{
  allowDiskUse: true
},
print(
  db.Or9.insert({
    "HomepageDomain":myDoc.homepage_domain,
    "location_city":myDoc.location_city
  })
)
```

Comment: Advice using "skip" and "limit" on large collection without proper indexing is a very bad idea.